# Python 2.7,window7// WHat is the parse error in #4 line? Please give me some solution to this my work

Tags: python, algorithm

I wanna write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user
enter 'done' and once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers
I programmed as below. but I can not figure out How to fix this programming

```
largest = None
smallest = None

    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    if inp == "done" : break
    if len(inp)<1 : break

    try:
        num=float(inp)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        continue

    if num<smallest:
        smallest=num

    print smallest

    if num>largest:
        largest=num
    print largest   

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting?  This won't run as entered.  If you don't understand what that means, your formatting probably IS the problem -- fix the different indents.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is missing a loop. You need to put

```
while True:
```

on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

You call break but you don't seem to be inside a loop.